# Conditional coloring formula on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm having a problem with conditional formatting on Google Sheets. I'm using the following formula for a range of cells:

```
=AND($N1=FALSE,$A1="link",AND($K1="",INDIRECT("import!$B1")<>"",OR(INDIRECT("import!$B1")=148,INDIRECT("import!$B1")=197)))
```

When I use the formula in a regular cell, the return value is TRUE, so in my mind the formula should work.

What's wrong with the formula?

Comment: Your formula works in the first row of a range, but it's not clear what you want to happen as you move down the range. It would be good if you could demonstrate with some sample data.

Comment: Uh, that is how conditional formatting works - you only reference one cell with `$` and all other rows act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've since solved the issue with an additional column that does all the checks required to make each line valid: `=AND(A3="link",B3<>"",D3<>"",F3<>"",I3<>"",M3<>"",NOT(AND(OR(import!B3=148,import!B3=197),K3="")))`
Was able to link the conditionally formatted column to this marker afterwards. I don't think it works otherwise.